# Using variable as parameter works, using source of variable fails

Tags: powershell

I found a way to get the current working directory into $dp0.

```
PS C:\src\powershell> Get-Content .\curdir2.ps1
$dp0 = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)

Set-Location -Path $dp0
Write-Host "location is set"

Set-Location -Path [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)

Write-Host (Get-Location).Path
```

Why is it that when I try to use the same way as a parameter to `Set-Location` it is an error? I think this may be something fundamental about the objects in Powershell. What do I need to know?

```
Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\src\powershell\curdir2.ps1'.
At C:\src\powershell\curdir2.ps1:6 char:1
+ Set-Location -Path [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($myInvocation.MyCommand.De ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentheses.
As you can see in PS ISE that entire parameter is interpreted as a literal string otherwise.
And always use `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path` to correctly handle directories with `[]` brackets.

```
Set-Location -LiteralPath ([IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition))
```

PS3.0+: `cd -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot`

Comment: I am giving you the check mark. Can you say anything more about why parentheses are needed? I do not think I have ever seen that in other languages.

Comment: PowerShell syntax is quite weird because it treats unquoted text as strings  for parameters of `string` and `string[]` (array of strings) types. And just like inside a string it only recognizes the variables `$var` and expressions `$(....)`. Bare parentheses are basically a shorthand of the latter when no quotes are used.